# Setup VPN access through SSH

Tags: ssh, vpn

I have a Samsung S4 with last kitkat update. I would like to set it up so that I can access my University services. For that, when I use my laptop, I just set up a ssh tunnel like:

```
ssh -D 8081 -f -C -q -N work_machine.edu
```

I wonder if this can be done in android and how, or if there is any app for doing this. I had a look to some VPN apps but found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The command you typed just does dynamic port forwarding through SSH connection. That's equivalent to SOCKS5 proxy. But you need to redirect your traffic towards this tunnel using VPN or `iptables`. Latter requires root access.

One such free and open-source app which makes use of VPN is SocksDroid. SSH tunnel can be created using some GUI or CLI app like Termux. For more options see [How to set up a socks5 with Android cli?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526)