# How to set up a socks5 with Android cli?

Tags: adb, root-access, shell, proxy

I found articles how to set up a [http-proxy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98287/how-to-set-wifi-proxy-via-adb-shell). But can't find any info, how to set up a socks5 proxy. My goal is to route all traffic from apps, etc throught this proxy. Is this possible? How then programs like Drony work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does have `HTTP(S)` proxy support built-in that can be set through `Settings` UI and/or command line, but it isn't global, so regarded by ***proxy-aware*** apps only. However there is no built-in support for `SOCKS`. So if an app - unlike web browsers - cannot be configured to use SOCKS proxy, there is no way to set SOCKS5 proxy from `adb shell` or terminal emulator without using a third party tool / app. See details in [How to set Wi-Fi HTTPS proxy, not HTTP, via adb shell?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217801/218526)

### HOW PROXY WORKS?

See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217801/218526) for HTTP(S) proxy.

SOCKS proxy - a complete handshake protocol - creates a tunnel at lower level than *application proxies* (`http/s`) in [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), so UDP traffic can also be transported. However the connection isn't secure like `https` and the security depends on initial authentication during handshake. `socks` can be used by individual clients or can be set system-wide i.e. to transparently forward all traffic. A common application of latter case is encrypted SOCKS tunnels like SSH dynamic forwarding, Tor, `shadowsocks`, `stunnel`, `ssf`, `sshuttle`, `obfsproxy` and so on. A VPN is also an encrypted tunnel but it operates even below SOCKS, therefore able to carry all IP traffic and forward every port.

### HOW TO SOCKSIFY:

Apps force all traffic towards a SOCKS proxy in two parts:

1. Establish a connection between client device and proxy server

   Proxy can be a standalone server or secure tunnel. In latter case the proxy is running usually on the client device itself or on local network. E.g. **Ki4a** has a builtin interface for SSH login to create a `Dynamic Forwarding` tunnel that acts as a local SOCKS proxy. **Shadowsocks** and **Orbot** (Tor) are two more examples of encrypted tunnels. Both listen on SOCKS5 as well as transparent proxy ports. **Drony** and **Postern** can also create `shadowsocks` tunnels. And the list goes on.
2. Redirect traffic from whole device or specific apps towards proxy

   Every app doesn't have built-in support to use SOCKS proxy, only a few apps such as web browsers have. So we need third party apps / native tools which use different approaches.

   Two common methods are `redsocks` + `iptables` and `tun2socks` + VPN/routing. **ProxyDroid** uses first approach. In latter case root is not required because apps  (like **SocksDroid**, **Orbot**, **Shadowsocks** and many other firewalls / sniffers) use Android's Java `VPN API`. **Drony** and **Postern** use Java based similar methods. **Ki4a** provides both options.

See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217801/218526) for other proxification methods.

---

Just as a reference, ***Shared library interceptor*** is a popular hack in Linux world (used by [socksify](https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/config/client.html), [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/about.php), [torsocks](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torsocks.git/tree/README.md), [proxychains](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) etc.). When a dynamic binary is run for some network communication, [`LD_PRELOAD`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) variable is used to force load a specific dynamic library in memory before any other shared libraries. Dynamic linker searches for required symbols in this library first. This library is modified to offer the same functions as the OS socket layer, but transparently translating plain connections to proxied connections by effectively taking control of functions/syscalls related to networking ([socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), [connect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) in particular). [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) and [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/) do something similar on Windows.

Though this approach is more relevant to native libraries and not Android's Java stack (where apps run), apps can be [hacked](https://serializethoughts.com/2017/04/01/working-of-ld_preload-for-android-applications-and-its-anti-re-technique) to start with specific `LD_PRELOAD` values. Android's *linker* does [support](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/linker/linker_main.cpp#358) `LD_PRELOAD`, see [Termux-exec](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-exec) for instance. But I haven't seen a practical example of this approach for proxy on Android.

---

### SETTING SOCKS PROXY WITH CLI:

While executing both above mentioned steps through command line isn't impossible, it's too complicated to be feasible for a common user. **redsocks** can be configured with `iptables` while **tun2socks** requires creating a `tun` network interface as well as configuring RPDB / routing table (that's what `VPN API` does at back end). **SSHuttle** is also similar project that's based on SSH and makes use of `iptables` NAT, TPROXY or routing. **ss-redir** (`shadowsocks`) also uses `iptables` NAT/TPROXY. Plus, ***all methods require root access***.

For a `redsocks`+`iptables` working example, see [How to send all internet traffic to a SOCKS5 proxy server in local network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221448/218526)

### CONCLUSION:

So to use SOCKS proxy on Android is best achieved using an app. **SocksDroid** is simple, free, open source and has no ads. Or you can use an app specific to a protocol e.g. Tor or Shadowsocks (I have no affiliation with any apps mentioned in this answer). But the selection depends on multiple factors like protocols / methods and one important being the `UDP` (particularly `DNS`) support.

---

**SOURCE:**

- [Comparison of proxifiers](https://en.everybodywiki.com/Comparison_of_proxifiers)