# Force proxy to be used by all of my Android applications

Tags: root-access, proxy

I'm looking to force some applications on my phone to use a proxy whose certificate is installed on my phone. Some applications (like Instagram, YouTube, etc.) are using this proxy and I can sniff the communication between my phone and the proxy.

To make this work, I need to use root permissions on my Android. I found an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroidn) that may help me do this, but I want to use the terminal to achieve this.

Any ideas that could help me would be appreciated.

Comment: IMHO your approach is wrong. You will never be able to force every app to use your proxy. Therefore use a separate network that is connected via transparent proxy to the Internet. Then you don't have to configure anything on the device.

Comment: @Robert thank you for your response. If I'm not dreadfully wrong the proxy that I am using uses a VPN to encrypt the data coming from my applications, the VPN then send those data to a VPN server that will decrypt them and finally transmit them to my server. So I already have a separate private network that is automatically created by the proxy. I'm trying this new approach because it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417242/do-android-proxy-settings-apply-to-all-apps-on-the-device) and it seems to be efficient.

Comment: Can be helpful: [How to set up a socks5 with Android cli?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526).

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.com/) does this using an Android app that uses the VPN mechanism to proxy all traffic through your HTTP Toolkit server.