# Is there a way to set a global http/https proxy on Android 8 either with root or no root?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, proxy

I am interested in setting up a global proxy on a rooted android 8.1.0 device. Is there a way to configure a system-wide proxy?

I have already tried a couple of apps to achieve this but have not had success.

shadowsocks - can't remove encryption and password setting. The password can be set blank but still does not seem to work as a plain proxy setup.

Proxy manager - doesn't allow you to set proxy host/ports manually. Only seems to support preset proxies

Drony - can't click on settings tab. I can only press turn on/off

ProxyDroid - keeps crashing. Does not run.

postern - insists on having an encryption method and user login credentials.

Comment: Related: [How to set up a socks5 with Android cli?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526)

Comment: Which kind of proxy you want to set? Is it a public one or do you have your own server?

Comment: I have my own local proxy server.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Regarding the socks5 question that you referred to, I looked at that and tried it and it doesn't work for me. The app runs but it is not behaving as an http proxy, but perhaps more as a socks5 proxy. I need an http/https proxy

Comment: Instead of a proxy server you should set-up a PPTP VPN server and configure your device to use this VPN server. In difference to a proxy a VPN is used by all connections.

Comment: @Robert For my use case, I need an http/https proxy specifically. A VPN would not be the right solution.

Comment: @user55570 I just mentioned the VPN as it captures all the traffic. On the VPN end point you can of course implements a transparent proxy which therefore also processes all data as you don't have to configure it on Android side.