# How to send all internet traffic to a SOCKS5 proxy server in local network?

Tags: networking, terminal, proxy, firewall, iptables

I got the inspiration [here](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android/blob/master/.github/faq.md). It looks like AFWall+ is able to create a NAT forwarding policy to keep all traffic going through a SOCKS5 proxy and fool Google apps into thinking they are not connected via a VPN (Google apps implement additional security measures when connecting via `VPNService` and if you are in China you will not pass the security check - the security check requests don't go through VPN, so they will EOF because GFW will kill these requests, read more [here](https://support.google.com/android/thread/28979027?hl=en)).

So my question is, if let's say I have a socks5 server running at `192.168.1.1:1088` which tunnels all connections via `vmess` protocol (aka `V2Ray`) to remote servers in the US, how do I create my custom script? I have tried:

```
IP6TABLES=/system/bin/ip6tables
IPTABLES=/system/bin/iptables
ULIMIT=/system/bin/ulimit
PORT=1088
SERVER=192.168.1.1
$ULIMIT -n 4096
$IP6TABLES -F
$IP6TABLES -A INPUT -j DROP
$IP6TABLES -A OUTPUT -j DROP
$IPTABLES -t nat -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -j RETURN
$IPTABLES -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j RETURN
$IPTABLES -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVER:$PORT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVER:$PORT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVER:$PORT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVER:$PORT
```

This does not work. So:

1. Did I create a wrong script? How do I create a script that does what I want to do?
2. Are there other settings that I should enable first? I didn't tick any app so I assume that means all app go through custom script, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [link](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android/blob/master/.github/faq.md) you have provided is not setting up SOCKS but a **transparent proxy** i.e. it takes TCP/UDP traffic and *SOCKSify* it before sending through `shadowsocks` tunnel. But you need to make your traffic *SOCKS-aware* before directing towards SOCKS proxy. Either configure individual apps (which have built-in support for SOCKS) or enforce proxy system-wide transparently (what you are trying to do).

### LIMITATIONS OF SOCKS PROXY:

> It looks like AFWall+ is able to create a NAT forwarding policy

AFWall+ uses `iptables` at back end and it can execute your script on network changes. Enforcing global proxy is (at least partially) possible with ***proxifier*** apps like [ProxyDroid](https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid) (which is `iptables`-based) and [SocksDroid](https://github.com/bndeff/socksdroid) (which is VPN/routing based). I have no affiliation with either.

If manually workig from CLI, you can use a transparent ***TCP/UDP-to-proxy redirector*** like [`redsocks`](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks) in combination with `iptables`. `shadowsocks` provides its own similar tool (`ss-redir`), so does Tor.

> I didn't tick any app so I assume that means all app go through custom script, right?

No. The problem with the `iptables` approach is that SOCKS5 is a layer 5 protocol in OSI model. So it ***cannot carry whole traffic from all apps***. Most of the traffic generated by apps is TCP which works fine with SOCKS and is easy to setup. But some games, VoIP apps and above all the traditional DNS generate **UDP** traffic which is not supported by many SOCKS5 proxies. E.g. `openssh` and `tor` both don't, `shadowsocks` however does have [UDP associate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928#section-7) features. But it **doesn't work** with simple `DNAT` or `REDIRECT` (probably because `SO_ORIGINAL_DST` is not available for UDP sockets, I don't know the details). You can possibly redirect traffic only towards a fixed socket (IP:PORT) e.g. a DNS server or game server.

[`TPROXY`](https://gsoc-blog.ecklm.com/iptables-redirect-vs.-dnat-vs.-tproxy) is the alternative here, but the trouble is that it works only with `PREROUTING` chain i.e. the traffic coming from outside, not that generated on device. So you have to do extra setup to route your on-device traffic without NATing towards a local proxy server (usually default gateway) where you'll set up `TPROXY`.

Complicated? That's why **VPN** is preferred. Even if you need to use a proxy to circumvent firewalls, VPN tunneling through proxy **spares you from the traffic redirection complexities**. VPN operates at lower level in network stack (L2/L3 in OSI), so it flawlessly carries all IP traffic including ICMP echos (`ping`) etc. which can no way be sent through SOCKS. Another plus point is that VPN can be tunneled through **transparent proxies** - like `shapeshifter-dispatcher` and `stunnel` - or SOCKS proxies which are meant to **forward only single port** - like `obfs4proxy`.

If not forwarding single port (tunneling), SOCKS5 must be an **application level proxy** i.e. it should be able to forward arbitrary ports from different apps like SSH dynamic port forwarding does.

[**`tun2socks`**](https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn/wiki/Tun2socks) is another SOCKSification method which collects TCP/UDP traffic on a `tun` interface (same like a VPN, no NAT involved) and forwards it through a SOCKS proxy. It recently added UDP associate support. Previously used **UDP Gateway** method also worked quite fine but it requires running a separate daemon (`udpgw`) along with proxy server. `tun2socks` is a **non-root solution** because apps - like `SocksDroid` and many other firewalls, sniffers etc. - using this method rely on Android's VPN facilities.

> ... and fool Google apps into thinking they are not connected via a VPN (Google apps implement additional security measures when connecting via `VPNService` ...

With both above methods (VPN through tunnel and Tun-to-SOCKS) it's not necessary to use Android's [VPNService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService) API (if that's causing problems for you). On a rooted device you can get a static `openvpn` or `tun2socks` binary and run that through CLI. That's far less hassle than setting up proxy through `iptables`. In former case, though, you need a VPN server obviously.

### `SOCKS`IFY WHOLE DEVICE:

As you don't want to go with VPN/routing based solution, here is the simple `iptables`-based method.

First get `redsocks` binary for your device architecture (or try [this one](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261728514) for `aarch64` or [this one](https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid/blob/master/app/src/main/assets/armeabi-v7a/redsocks) for `armeabi-v7a`).
Create configuration file:

```
// redsocks.conf

// general configuration
base {
    redirector = iptables;
}

// for TCP
redsocks {
    local_ip = "127.0.0.1"; local_port = "12345";
    ip = "192.168.1.1"; port = "1088"; type = socks5;
}

// for UDP, assuming your SOCKS5 proxy supports UDP associate
redudp {
    local_ip = "127.0.0.1"; local_port = "12345";
    ip = "192.168.1.1"; port = "1088";
    dest_ip = "1.1.1.1"; dest_port = "53";  /* set whatever DNS server */
}
```

<sup>* See [redsocks.conf.example](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/blob/master/redsocks.conf.example) for details and more options.</sup>

Run:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

IPTABLES="/system/bin/iptables -w5 -t nat"

# create new chain
$IPTABLES -N PROXY
$IPTABLES -I OUTPUT -j PROXY

# exclude local traffic, see: http://manpages.org/ss-redir
$IPTABLES -A PROXY -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
$IPTABLES -A PROXY -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN

# socksify whole TCP traffic
$IPTABLES -A PROXY -p tcp -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:12345

# socksify only DNS UDP traffic
$IPTABLES -A PROXY -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:12345

echo "Ctrl^C to exit."
trap "$IPTABLES -D OUTPUT -j PROXY; $IPTABLES -F PROXY; $IPTABLES -X PROXY" EXIT

# run socksifier
redsocks -c /path/to/redsocks.conf
```

You can add custom `iptables` script to AFWall+. `redsocks` can be run as `init` service with non-root UID, dropped capabilities and restricted SELinux context. See [How to run an executable on boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526)

---

**RELATED:**

- [Why is not all traffic captured from my device when routing through proxy?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219280/218526)
- [How to set up a socks5 with Android CLI?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526)

Comment: Your redsocks + iptables solution worked but I had to correct several things to use Dante SOCKS proxy on Anbox. For the first iptables command, I got error `unknown option "-w5"`. Adding a space before the number did not solve the problem. Anbox used Android 7 (x86) with iptables v1.4.20 and the -w parameter did not accept any value. Is this parameter necessary? I did not need to use it. Then I had to comment the iptables command for UDP, otherwise DNS would not work. In redsocks.conf, I also had to comment the redudp block because of the error `file parsing error at line 13: unknown section`.

Comment: @baptx for `-w` see [`iptables` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html). // UDP is officially supported by `redsocks`: https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/blob/master/redsocks.conf.example#L117. It doesn't work for you because your proxy doesn't have **UDP associate** feature. So you can't send DNS or any other UDP traffic through proxy. That's what I've explained under **LIMITATIONS OF SOCKS PROXY**. Please go through the answer completely for better understanding. // May be you need an empty line at `.conf` end: https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/issues/134

Comment: I still got the file parsing error on the redudp line, even with an empty line at the end of the config file. It looks like this configuration is not supported by the version of redsocks I am using. I downloaded the x86 build of redsocks from ProxyDroid. With `redsocks -v`, I can see that they are using an older version, 0.4 instead of latest 0.5.

Comment: @baptx UDP is supported since version 0.1: https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/commit/c0d4cede5a43e552017f2696d5b80dc2741e3190#diff-d64baa8264254662e7f0007c0f4fa939. But you may consider building from latest source.

Comment: @IrfanLatif how to use TPROXY instead of DNAT? here not all UDP traffic is redirected.

Comment: @hldev read the link given in the answer. Or any other TPROXY setup guide on internet.

Comment: @IrfanLatif yes, I found TPROXY can be used only from PREROUTING, so I cant route the output like you did, redsocks must run on another machine.