# Android cannot forward packets

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

#### Target:

Perform IP forwarding for devices within the same local network. (The real target is transparent proxy but the IP forwarding is a prerequisite)

#### Network setup:

All devices are in the same local network `192.168.0.0/16`.

- main router `192.168.1.1`
- Android phone `192.168.2.1` (network interface `wlan0`)
- computer `192.168.2.10` gateway set as `192.168.2.1`
- others like Raspberry Pi at `192.168.1.11`

#### Android setup:

- Data disabled, only WiFi connects.
- rooted Android 10 (Pixel 2 XL)
- enabled ip forwarding by `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- netfilter: on all tables of nat, mangle, filter and raw, run `iptables -F -t <table_name>` and `iptables -X -t <table_name>`
- rp_filter: Disable by `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0` and `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.rp_filter=0`

#### Result:

- the computer cannot access to the Internet, `ping`, `dig`, browser, nothing works.
- the computer connects to local devices without any problem (like ping router `192.168.1.1`, SSH to the Raspberry Pi, or use FireFox through the SOCK5 proxy hosted on the Pi).
- Android phone connects to the Internet perfectly.

#### Debug:

- using `iptables -t <table_name> -L -v` to show packet count, all chains have some packets, *except the `FORWARD` chain of both `raw`, `mangle` tables shows `Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)`. After some googling, rp_filter is the suspect but I'm sure it's turned off.

Comment: NetFilter (`iptables`) operates at higher OSI layer. What about IP routing (`ip rule` and `ip route`)? Are they set up correctly? Android doesn't use `main` table by default, unlike normal Linux distros. Related: [How to send all internet traffic to a SOCKS5 proxy server in local network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221448/218526) and [How to port-forward internet using Android Hotspot to PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207342/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Irfan Latif](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/218526/irfan-latif), I found the solution myself.
It's right that packets are sent to the last `unreachable` rule of `ip rule`, because they fail to match any previous rules:

```
# result of `ip rule`
... (no rules match)
22000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0xffff iif lo lookup wlan0 
32000:  from all unreachable
```

So I added a rule to route incoming traffic from local network to route table `wlan0` by:
`ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/16 iif wlan0 table wlan0`