# How to block a specific URL phonewide

Tags: ads, hosts

My first thought was blocking them using AdAway or AFWall, but ironically, an adblock and a firewall are useless

Most of the URLs are pictures. I can easily get their URL

I ask to block it phonewide because my browser doesn't support custom adblocking

Didn't even try adding some lines to the phone Hosts, because my adblock overwrites it.

- A replacement for the AdAway is very well on the table (if not VPN-based), but for the AfWall, only if it's as lightweight, as well organized, free, and again, not VPN-based
- My browser is Opera. Not changing that.

In case AdAway can be used:  If the URL needs to be a line of a host source,  how should it be formatted ?

Thank you ahead

Comment: Adaway is not content blocker. It is hosts blocker. You add only hosts (domain names and addresses). It has no capability (AFAIK) to block content sourced from a domain. To block content, you need something granular. In case of a browser, say Firefox, you can use Ublock Origin extension. For apps, I don't know what would work.

Comment: Changed the whole thread to put more options on the table

Comment: You can run [`tinyproxy`](https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy) server on your Android device. It supports `FilterURLs` option. To force redirect all traffic towards this local server, you can use [`redsocks2`](https://github.com/semigodking/redsocks) with `http-connect` type. Both tools are free and open source. For hints see my answers to [Using your Android phone as a proxy server](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217831/218526) and [How to send all internet traffic to a SOCKS5 proxy server in local network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221448/218526).

Comment: Man... Above my level... After reading twice, my brain became barely capable of Installing tinyproxy... Now the rest... All I can do is thank you for the attention and shared knowledge 

Comment: Can your solution, or another strategy you may know, be adapted to a "script" that AFWall can swallow ?

Comment: Yes. You can run the CLI software in a shell script; directly or through AFWall. // Actually it's more complicated than what I wrote. `FilterURLs` won't work for HTTPS traffic without decryption (MITM) because in the case of SSL/TLS traffic the whole URL is not visible to the proxy. So a transparent intercepting proxy is needed. Without SSL interception only domains can be filtered using proxy. But a simpler approach to filter domains is DNS filtering using `hosts` file or by running a small DNS server (see example of [`dnscrypt`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526)).

Comment: Explanation on transparent HTTPS proxy can be found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219280/218526) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217801/218526).