# Resolve dns through proxy > ProxyDroid

Tags: proxy, dns

Android device and rooted and using ProxyDroid App with HTTP Proxy
one of the main problem with ProxyDroid App is dns leak . it's ether showing my original DNS or Google DNS . i want to Resolve dns through proxy so that it match the IP address Country .

i already have another App can do that but the main reason of using ProxyDroid is to force global proxy for all installed app and it's the only app can do that as far as i can tell ,

this is the dns address in my device wifi connection and it looks like ProxyDroid is using them
DNS 1 > 192.168.0.1
DNS 2 > 8.8.8.8

i just don't know to what address should i changed them in order to resolve the dns through proxy . any help please ? Thanks

Comment: ProxyDroid uses `redsocks` for HTTP and SOCKS proxy under the hood. You can [configure `redsocks` manually from commandline](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221448/218526) and make it [redirect DNS](https://github.com/semigodking/redsocks#redirect-udp-based-dns-request-via-tcp-connection) as well.